# Extension fields of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $\mathbb Q$ be the field of rationals. 
>   Let $m_1, m_2,\dots, m_k$ be in $\mathbb N^*$.
>   Let $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_k$ be in $\mathbb N$.
>   Suppose  $t_i^{1/m_i}$ $\neq $    $q t_j^{1/m_j}$ for any $i$ and $j$, for all $q\in\mathbb Q$ and if $\gcd (t_i , t_j )\neq 1$ then $\gcd (m_i , m_j ) = 1$.
>    Then is it always true that
>   $$\mathbb Q ( t_1^{1/m_1}, t_2^{1/m_2}, \dots ,t_k^{1/m_k} ) = \mathbb Q( t_1^{1/m_1} + t_2^{1/m_2} + \dots  + t_k^{1/m_k} )?$$

It is trivial that any element of $$\mathbb Q( t_1^{1/m_1} + t_2^{1/m_2} + \dots  + t_k^{1/m_k} )$$ expressed as   $$q + a( t_1^{1/m_1} + t_2^{1/m_2} + \dots  + t_k^{1/m_k} )$$ with $a,q \in \mathbb Q$ is in $$\mathbb Q ( t_1^{1/m_1} , t_2^{1/m2} , \dots ,t_k^{1/m_k} ).$$

Now, the only thing that needs to be checked is whether $$\mathbb Q ( t_1^{1/m_1} , t_2^{1/m_2} , \dots ,t_k^{1/m_k} )$$ is a subset of $$\mathbb Q( t_1^{1/m_1} + t_2^{1/m_2} + \dots  + t_k^{1/m_k} ).$$ I either need to prove it or I need a counter-example.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: I did a little bit of editing. Manasi, please have a look at what I did, and do the rest.

Comment: Thank You for editing this question. I hope that this should be okay now.